# Scriptural references for Hanumāna Jyotish

Tags: scripture, rama, astrology, hanuman

I came across this book, Hanumāna Jyotish ( हनुमान ज्योतिष ) which has been compiled by various astrologers under several different publications and all of them, supposedly attributes the original authorship to Lord Hanuman.

Here's two of the screenshots of the said book, just for reference purposes :-

[image: Cover Page of the Book]
[image: Starting page of the 1st Chapter]

I could not find any English translation for this but basically here's the summarised English translation of the hindi translation that has been provided in the book:-

> Lord Rāma, during his stay at the ṛṣyamūka mountain (ऋष्यमूक
> पर्वत), asks Lord Hanumāna on his learnings from the Sun God ( सूर्य-
> नारायण)

> Lord Hanumāna answers - he learnt all the vedic and scripture
> knowledge. Amongst all of them, the treatise on Jyotish (ज्योतिष) is the one that
> fulfills all desires and wishes, thus if he (Lord Rāma) be pleased so
> might [Lord Hanumāna] request something?

So my question is on the references and exact source of this variety of astrology ( ज्योतिष)? Does it have any basis in any of the Indian scriptures?